# Ruby-debug's "ps" command not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-debug

I'm diving into how to use the Ruby Debugger (ruby-debug), specifically in a Rails app. It seems that the `ps` command within rdb should evaluate an expression, sort it, and columnize the value. All of that is working except columnizing, it just lists them from the top down.

Am I missing something obvious here? The exact command I'm running within rdb is `ps private_methods`.

The version of rdb I'm using is ruby-debug 0.10.4

Answer (score 2):

If you are serious about debugging, try [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry)